# Can't show paginations (dots) in OwlCarousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used [owl carousel](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2) to create a slideshow, but can't show dots or pagination. I read the [documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html) and it was stated that it takes key word argument `dots: true|false`, but when I used `dots: true` it doesn't show. I also tried `pagination: true`.

```
<script>
  $(".slider").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 2000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    dots: true,
  });
</script>
```

[here](https://codepen.io/basirpayenda/pen/ExPqxMW?editors=1000) is a pen for full review. Thanks for help

Comment: usually you should tag a javascript question with javascript. Owl carousel seems to have broken functionality, it still outputs the pagination/dots in the HTML, but has a CSS class to hide it regardless if you set true or false. you just need to override the default CSS.

Comment: yes, I forgot. I can make custom one, but was wondering why the built-in one doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have enough items to trigger the dots. Your loop is 3 and your amount of cards is 3. There is no pagination to show.Also you need to add the class `owl-theme` to your container with the `owl-carousel` class and you need a theme file from Owl Carousel, there are a few CDN's and you need any CSS file with theme in the name.

Here's an example with the default theme: https://codepen.io/JHeth/pen/QWyewpy

Comment: Thank you @JHeth, I missed those details